# Xamarin: How to Display a Small Part of Webpage in [Android] WebView?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview

I'm trying to display only a small part of a webpage in Xamarin Android Webkit WebView.  I've seen a lot of answers how to do this in android studio but I've not seen many recent answers for how to do it in xamarin for android.  What method would you recommend for this task?  I could also settle for loading a WebView and then scrolling down to a certain section of a page.

Here's the code I'm using to generate tab and WebView

```
//Discover new content
[Activity]
//define class discover content
public class SessionsActivity : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.discover);

        //declare webview and tell our code where to find the XAML resource
        WebView discoverWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewDiscover);

        //set the webview client
        discoverWebView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        //load the subscription url
        discoverWebView.LoadUrl("https://www.bitchute.com/");
        //enable javascript in our webview
        discoverWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        //zoom control on?  This should perhaps be disabled for consistency?
        //we will leave it on for now
        discoverWebView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
        discoverWebView.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
        //scrollbarsdisabled
        // subWebView.ScrollBarStyle = ScrollbarStyles.OutsideOverlay;
        discoverWebView.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;


    }
}
```

thanks, in advance! =]

Comment: "not seen many recent answers" - just because an answer is not recent doesn't mean it's not valid.  If you tried it and it didn't work, then tell us what you tried.  And "lot of answers how to do this in android studio" - the API calls between Android and Xamarin are generally the same, although the syntax may vary.  If you're not sure how to translate some Android Java into Xamarin C#, then ask about that specifically.

Comment: I haven't even tried this because I don't know how to convert the syntax from java to C#

Comment: webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
            "document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display="none"; " +
            "})()");

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the Xamarin docs for [WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Webkit.WebView/#Public_Methods), you'll see that it has a [LoadURL](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Webkit.WebView.LoadUrl/p/System.String/) method with the same signature as the Java method.  The only difference is the casing of the method - Xamarin usually uses C# casing, but otherwise the method names are the same, and the argument you pass will also be identical

```
discoverWebView.LoadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
"document.getElementsByTagName('header'[0].style.display="none"; " + 
"})()");
```

Comment: syntax is not correct, I'll post the code once I figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, @Jason was helpful but a more complete answer is as follows, this loads duckduckgo.com then hides the content_homepage, scroll to mid-bottom:

```
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Widget;

namespace BottomNavigationViewPager.Fragments
{
    public class TheFragment1 : Fragment
    {
        string _title;
        string _icon;

        protected static WebView _wv;

        public static TheFragment1 NewInstance(string title, string icon) {
            var fragment = new TheFragment1();
            fragment.Arguments = new Bundle();
            fragment.Arguments.PutString("title", title);
            fragment.Arguments.PutString("icon", icon);
            return fragment;
        }

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (Arguments != null)
            {
                if(Arguments.ContainsKey("title"))
                    _title = (string)Arguments.Get("title");

                if (Arguments.ContainsKey("icon"))
                    _icon = (string)Arguments.Get("icon");
            }
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TheFragmentLayout1, container, false);

            _wv = view.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);

            var _wvc = new MyWebViewClient();




            _wv.SetWebViewClient(_wvc);

            //string _wtf = "header";



            _wv.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

            _wv.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;

            _wv.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;




            //_wvc.OnPageFinished(_wv, _jsHideBannerC);



            _wv.LoadUrl("https://www.duckduckgo.com/");

            return view;
        }

        private class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {
            public override void OnPageStarted(WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
            {
                base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);


            }

            public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
            {
                base.OnPageFinished(view, url);


                string _jsHideBanner = "javascript:(function() { " +
                                "document.getElementById('content_homepage').style.display='none'; " + "})()";

                string _jsHideBannerC = "javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('logo-wrap--home').style.display='none'; " + "})()";

                _wv.LoadUrl(_jsHideBanner);
            }


        }
    }
    }
```